# Constraints and dates - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a graduation year column that is only allowed to be a year(4 digits)

and has the constraint of dob year + atleast 10 years.

Something like :

***dob DATE CHECK (dob < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
graduation_year DATE CHECK (graduation_year >= dob + 10)***

How would i get this to work?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Have you looked at Check Constraints in Postgres? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS

Answer (score 0):

Because two columns are involved, the constraint becomes a table constraint and can't be associated to a column. See the [doc] (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS).

You must also specify that you are adding years

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
 dob DATE CHECK (dob < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
 graduation_year DATE,
 CHECK (graduation_year >= dob + interval '10 years')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'm looking to be able to input something like `INSERT INTO myTable  (dob,  graduation_year) VALUES ('2005-05-05', 2020);`and have it work. Right now it needs a full date.

Comment: @Painkilleryo It would have been easier if the `graduation_year` was just an `int` instead of a `date`. You can insert using `insert into myTable values (date '2021/01/01',to_date('2022','YYYY'));` but remember that it won't just record 2022 but rather 2022/01/01